# Arduino inductance meter using op-amp as comparator?

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, comparator

I want to create an Inductance meter with an arduino nano, for that I follow 
that link whose theory convinced me : [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGjV5vUvGPc)

(**The Diode on schematic remove analog negative voltage, Edit: I have wrong,  excuse me surely for prevent inductor negative voltage because out signal not contain diode or maybe in the comparator ?**) and then the comparator 
convert it into square wave based on ON/OFF DC ?
Getting wavelenght or pulse in time and then calculating resonant frequency 
and finally the inductor value based on known capacitors values.

This tutorial use an LM339N comparator, but I learn an I read : op-amp can be used as comparator.

I have not a comparator but I have an TLV2462 op-amp ,can I use this 
[TLV2462 - Op Amp - Dual Rail-to-Rail](https://www.adafruit.com/product/808) as comparator 
in place of LM329N comparator ?

My goal is to create an Inductance meter for 'nH' unit... I learn, I read but i'm confuse.
Also, I know the discharge inductor can create a big negative voltage spike.
I would not want to burn my arduino (perhaps the diode is here for that), that's why I'm always on the theoretical part.

Thank's for your help.

[image]

Comment: Try to extract the schematic from the video, and edit it into your question.  I'm not going to wade through some fuzzy video looking for it.

Comment: Note that an ATmega already includes a comparator, which is typically utilized when making capacitance measurements.  Have you evaluated if it is suitable?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, thank's, I did not know and I saw that nowhere. But how should I go about it for inductance

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to perform this measurement but when it comes down to nH accuracy every mm of trace length counts as adds 0.5~1 nH/mm.

The Op Amp must support the current and bandwidth required to drive the low impedance of nH ranges.

Another possible method is to use a linear LC oscillator , limiter and 8 bit binary binary counter to lower the frequency measurement.

http://www.falstad.com/circuit-java/e-eclosc.html

Comment: Enable site java in browser for the simulation to work. Change anything you want.

Comment: For the moment i want to try it with op-amp, i read on op-amp TLV2462: 6 MHz gain bandwidth & 1.6 V/us slew so you can drive fairly fast signals, this is good for nH ? thank's

Comment: define good nH.  resolution ? accuracy? please

Comment: accuracy and/on nano henries unit. thank's again

Comment: Have you ever made a 1nH measurement before?  What impedance of 1nH at 6MHz? ( skill test) and what current is needed for resonant cap at 5MHz and 1nH using 1.6V/us=dV/dt

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, but you haven't thought about his enough.  Always present realistic Specs 1st before even thinking of using an Arduino or a comparator.

Comment: There are far simpler ways after you tell me your answers.

Comment: Not at all, some tests of calculations but I am at the beginning of my learning and I am at the stage where I store information, try to understand them and then apply them. You put me on the path and I thank you very much for that. I will work on your last comment which seems to me a good starting point indeed. thank you again for your time and indulgence.

Comment: The simulator link I posted will work easier if you replace ground with 2.5V and -5.2 with 0V (gnd) in a small PCB with pads for inductor. Then use largest value plastic only film caps  you can fit. E.g 1uF yields X MHz with 1nH.  This can be direct coupled out into 5.0V 74HCxx logic inverter to get a high speed clock which you can divide down, if you like, with an async ripple counter and measure frequency or number of cycles counted with an accurate  1 pps count.   The outputs in binary can be displayed on LEDs then compute L.

Comment: To be honest, I could not see the simulator that you recommend because I do not have Java installed for my browser, so I looked on Falstad Online Circuit Simulator Applet and in the examples of circuits I found in Circuits -> Transistors -> Oscillators -> Emitter-Coupled Oscillator LC , but I do not know if it corresponds to what you recommend me so I did not want to dwell on it moreI do not have no components at hand other than transistors, resistors, diodes, capacitors and an op-amp. ( a starter kit )

Comment: I also found it interesting to understand the op-amp in the same stride for my little level.  From now on I will work on your comments and recommendations.
I thank you again for your time and attention.